# Flash vs Browser Cookies - pros and cons

Tags: flash, cookies, browser

For the first time, I need to use the cookie functionality. The question is:
What are the cons and pros of using Flash vs Browser cookies?

Answer (score 0):

There's no pros or cons, they both work the same way.